# Establish relationship from one table to another table in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have 2 tables, one table is

> City Table ( int id, string name)

and my another table is

> Distance  table(int id,int cityId (FK city),int neighbourId(FK city))

I want to use Hibernate but I can't establish a relationship between these  tables in Hibernate.

Comment: what is your problem, why can't you make those relationships?

Comment: i  made it via Hibernate tool ,but  my issue was  object representations of these  tables.i solved it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about something like

```
<class name="City" table="CITIES">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" />
    <set name="neighbours" table="DISTANCES">      
        <key column="city_id" />
        <many-to-one name="neighbour" class="City" />
    </set>
</class>
```

didn't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can see any problem to do it normally.

```
<class name="City" table="CITY">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="name" />
</class>
<class name="Distance" table="DISTANCE">
    <id name="id" type="integer">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="city" column="cityId" class="City"/>
    <many-to-one name="neighbour" column="neighbourId" class="City"/>
</class>
```

didn't test it neither.